# Newbie in Unit Testing - How would you test this code using Jest Testing?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

I'm a newbie in Unit Testing.
I want to learn how to test correctly using Jest and after articles, demos, and a course on Udemy, I'm still pretty confused (especially using Jest mocking).
I should mention that all our code is outside react so it seems to confuse me even more.

I've written an AB test for my company and already recognized it should be easy to test but I don't think I'm doing it right. It seems like I'm just copying my original code over to test and although I feel the function is validated, it seems wrong to me.

Here's my code in question and the test. How would you guys who have more experience do this "right"?

Thanks!

JS:

```
let ABTestValue = 30;
ABTest();

export function ABTest() {
  const roll = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);

  if (debugMode) {
    console.log('TimedRefresh - AB Test Issue-831 (90 and above get their refresh time changed) randomized value = ', roll);
  }

  const ABTestMappings = [
    {
      roll: 90,
      ABTestValue: 40
    },
    {
      roll: 91,
      ABTestValue: 40
    },
    {
      roll: 92,
      ABTestValue: 50
    },
    {
      roll: 93,
      ABTestValue: 50
    },
    {
      roll: 94,
      ABTestValue: 60
    },
    {
      roll: 95,
      ABTestValue: 60
    },
    {
      roll: 96,
      ABTestValue: 70
    },
    {
      roll: 97,
      ABTestValue: 70
    },
    {
      roll: 98,
      ABTestValue: 80
    },
    {
      roll: 99,
      ABTestValue: 80
    }
  ];

  if (roll > 89 && roll < 100) {
    ABTestValue = ABTestMappings.filter((a) => a.roll === roll)[0].ABTestValue;
  }

  window.rg_version = `time${ABTestValue}`;

  if (debugMode) {
    console.log('TimedRefresh - ABTestValue - change in refresh time in seconds (30 is default) - ', ABTestValue);
  }
}
```

test.js:

```
import { ABTest } from './index';

describe('ABTEST test', () => {
  it('ABTest function', () => {
    expect(ABTest).toBeDefined();
  })

  describe('test different rolls', () => {
    const ABTestMappings = [
      {
        roll: 90,
        ABTestValue: 40
      },
      {
        roll: 91,
        ABTestValue: 40
      },
      {
        roll: 92,
        ABTestValue: 50
      },
      {
        roll: 93,
        ABTestValue: 50
      },
      {
        roll: 94,
        ABTestValue: 60
      },
      {
        roll: 95,
        ABTestValue: 60
      },
      {
        roll: 96,
        ABTestValue: 70
      },
      {
        roll: 97,
        ABTestValue: 70
      },
      {
        roll: 98,
        ABTestValue: 80
      },
      {
        roll: 99,
        ABTestValue: 80
      }
    ];

    const roll = 92;
    const roll2 = 95;
    const roll3 = 99;
    const roll4 = 80;
    let ABTestValue = 30;
    let ABTestValue2 = 30;
    let ABTestValue3 = 30;
    let ABTestValue4 = 30;

    if (roll > 89 && roll < 100) {
      ABTestValue = ABTestMappings.filter((a) => a.roll === roll)[0].ABTestValue;
    }

    if (roll2 > 89 && roll2 < 100) {
      ABTestValue2 = ABTestMappings.filter((a) => a.roll === roll2)[0].ABTestValue;
    }

    if (roll3 > 89 && roll3 < 100) {
      ABTestValue3 = ABTestMappings.filter((a) => a.roll === roll3)[0].ABTestValue;
    }

    if (roll4 > 89 && roll4 < 100) {
      ABTestValue4 = ABTestMappings.filter((a) => a.roll === roll4)[0].ABTestValue;
    }

    it('if roll is 92', () => {
      if (roll) {
        expect(ABTestValue).toEqual(50);
      }
    })

    it('if roll is 95', () => {
      if (roll2) {
        expect(ABTestValue2).toEqual(60);
      }
    })

    it('if roll is 99', () => {
      if (roll3) {
        expect(ABTestValue3).toEqual(80);
      }
    })

    it('if roll is less than 90', () => {
      if (roll4) {
        expect(ABTestValue4).toEqual(30);
      }
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: Yeah, this seems wrong. You don't need to test if `ABTestValue` is defined and the correct value was assigned, when all you do in your test is define the variable and give it a value. You are testing if the language works the way it should, which is redundant. In general, you don't *copy code* and test if it behaves correctly - if the function is re-written, then your test becomes useless. What you do is *call the function* with some input and check what the output is. You should know what to expect. Test around edge cases (e.g., `null`/wrong input) and verify the function behaves as defined.

Comment: It's *fine* if you supply a number when a function expects a string, or a negative number when it expects a positive one - it can error or gracefully tell you "wrong input" or whatever, your test should verify the *expected* thing happens. The idea is that if the function is re-written, your test should still pass as long as the new code behaves the same. If a test fails, then the new code doesn't behave the same.

Comment: Thanks guys. So wondering if I could ask for an example of how you’d write it correctly though. I thought to use jest.fn() if that’s what you refer to but could not get it working. I need some better examples than the general ones online to really help me understand how to do it right. I appreciate it! My goal is to try to write using TDD in the near future but I’m still pretty confused at how to test something more intricate than existence and should equal :p

Comment: Yeah, these are great tips @VLAZ, thanks. So digging in further, I'm not sure how to make calling the function work. It's true, I will take those first tests out bc that's the method of the function right now and I shouldn't need to test those things. But, feeding in values, that the second part, i'm feeding in an edge case and cases that should work. I am thinking I am testing that part right. Hopefully I am, any other tips are appreciated, thanks.

Comment: The most helpful way to structure your tests is the **A**rrange, **A**ct, **A**ssert steps. There are other names but I find the AAA easier to remember. The idea is simple 1. you *arrange* the test - set up any data or functionality needed. It could be as simple as `input = "my input value"` 2. You *act* - you call the functionality with the input data and/or anything else needed `output = capitalize(input)`. 3. *assert* - check if everything was correct `expect(output).toBe("MY INPUT VALUE")`. Each step can be longer or shorter (e.g., arrangement might be nonexistent) but it's useful to

Comment: think of breaking the tests into these three phases. I even put comments above each, if there are many lines in a test. Another helpful guideline is 1 unit test = 1 assertion. It's not a mandatory thing but it does help making the tests self contained and makes it easy to find what broke. Instead of asserting the input is null, the correct, within bounds, and the correct value at once, make each of these a separate test. Then if `testOutputIsNotNull` breaks, you don't have to track it down.

Comment: Wow these are great tips, thanks! I refactored the test above a little just to take out the test on the language you mentioned. It's true, I shouldn't have to test that. So how about what I've done in my test above? I Arranged data to test the different scenarios (bc if i should use jest mocks, i still don't know how) and I think I tested the cases I need. So I know it works. BUT yes, if the code in the JS changes, the tests are still the old code, that doesn't help, there must be a better way? How did you learn to test? Thinking about how to seems to be the hardest step. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The unit test workflow is very simple.

1. Mock the dependencies and their return value for the method/function you want to test. Make an isolated environment for it. The principle is the unit tests shouldn't depend on any external service, e.g. send a real HTTP request, query the real database, access the real file system.
2. Execute the method/function you want to test, test each branch(`if...else`, `switch...case`), statements, functions, and lines. They are the summary of the coverage report.
3. Assert(`expect`) the result and if the methods/functions on which the method/function being tested depends are to be called. Why? Because we should make sure the code execute as we expect

Test each method/function as the above workflow in each software arch layer.

The software arch layer means, for example, data access layer, model layer,  service layer, controller/router layer

Here is the correct unit test:

`index.ts`:

```js
(window as any).rg_version = '';

export function ABTest(debugMode = false) {
  const roll = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  let ABTestValue = 30;

  if (debugMode) {
    console.log(
      'TimedRefresh - AB Test Issue-831 (90 and above get their refresh time changed) randomized value = ',
      roll
    );
  }

  const ABTestMappings = [
    {
      roll: 90,
      ABTestValue: 40
    },
    {
      roll: 91,
      ABTestValue: 40
    },
    {
      roll: 92,
      ABTestValue: 50
    },
    {
      roll: 93,
      ABTestValue: 50
    },
    {
      roll: 94,
      ABTestValue: 60
    },
    {
      roll: 95,
      ABTestValue: 60
    },
    {
      roll: 96,
      ABTestValue: 70
    },
    {
      roll: 97,
      ABTestValue: 70
    },
    {
      roll: 98,
      ABTestValue: 80
    },
    {
      roll: 99,
      ABTestValue: 80
    }
  ];

  if (roll > 89 && roll < 100) {
    ABTestValue = ABTestMappings.filter(a => a.roll === roll)[0].ABTestValue;
  }

  (window as any).rg_version = `time${ABTestValue}`;

  if (debugMode) {
    console.log('TimedRefresh - ABTestValue - change in refresh time in seconds (30 is default) - ', ABTestValue);
  }
}
```

`index.spec.ts`:

```js
import { ABTest } from './';

describe('ABTest', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
    (window as any).rg_version = '';
  });
  it('should filter and get the correct value', () => {
    const floorSpy = jest.spyOn(Math, 'floor').mockReturnValueOnce(90);
    const logSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'log');
    ABTest();
    expect((window as any).rg_version).toBe('time40');
    expect(floorSpy).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(logSpy).toBeCalledTimes(0);
  });

  it('should get default value', () => {
    const floorSpy = jest.spyOn(Math, 'floor').mockReturnValueOnce(80);
    const logSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'log');
    ABTest(true);
    expect((window as any).rg_version).toBe('time30');
    expect(floorSpy).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(logSpy.mock.calls[0]).toEqual([
      'TimedRefresh - AB Test Issue-831 (90 and above get their refresh time changed) randomized value = ',
      80
    ]);
    expect(logSpy.mock.calls[1]).toEqual([
      'TimedRefresh - ABTestValue - change in refresh time in seconds (30 is default) - ',
      30
    ]);
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/58258206/index.spec.ts
  ABTest
    ✓ should filter and get the correct value (8ms)
    ✓ should get default value (6ms)

  console.log node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:860
    TimedRefresh - AB Test Issue-831 (90 and above get their refresh time changed) randomized value =  80

  console.log node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:860
    TimedRefresh - ABTestValue - change in refresh time in seconds (30 is default) -  30

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.814s, estimated 6s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/58258206

Comment: Oh, apologize for my last comment, got a little confused. I see you're using spyOn, I've not run across that yet. Let me check this out. I like how you showed me the coverage as well. I can use that to make sure I've tested everything too. Slipped my mind. Thanks. Gotta research your test a bit to really understand it. Thanks

Comment: @nyhunter77 Glad to help. Update the answer.

Comment: So apology @slideshowp2, finally had time to check out the answer with my code. Since I'm not using TS, things are breaking. I think i fixeed "window as any" code with just window.rg_version but the second test is not working right -expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality
    Expected: "time30"
    Received: "time40" - I'm trying to fix it but also trying to learn what spyOn is at the same time. ideas? shortcut? if you can explain a little more, thanks! Trying to work it out.

Comment: @nyhunter77 Take a note about `let ABTestValue = 30;` scope, You put this variable in a es6 module, it's module scope. I put it into the function, it's function scope. Every time the function executes, the value of `ABTestValue` is `30`.  If you put it in a module scope, after ran the first unit test, its value will be changed by your function logic, that's why second unit test failed.

Comment: I thought that every test was independent though and ran it's own scope though. In any case, I've tried resetting the values using beforeEach and still have this issue. Also moved the instantiation of ABTestValue into the function in index.js and that didn't resolve the issue. Shouldn't there be a way to reset the value in the test itself? As mentioned, using beforeEach and assigning ABTestValue = 30 or changing the value at the end of the first test don't seem to work. Still receiving time40 so I haven't found the answer yet.